# Python optimization of boxes within boxes

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize

edit: I believe I am missing a key component to this question which is the minimum acceptable dimensions of each square (in the real world they will have to be cut with a saw mill blade). I will repost the question or edit once I find out, but maybe there is still a general answer supposing I *did* have the constraints on minimum dimensions

I have a question that I don't really know where to start with in terms of coding in Python.

I have a problem where I have a square with dimensions 6" x 6" (eventually when I code for this I will want the dimensions to be variables but for the sake of writing this question it is probably helpful to use real numbers.

At the center of that perfect square I am going to cut out a perfect square of 4" x 4". This leaves me with a remaining surface area of 20 sq. inches.

Now, I am going to cut around that 4" x 4" 3 more "squares." They are technically hollow squares as the 4" x 4" center is its own entity. Each "square" will have different dimensions in terms of height and width. Consider a hollow box constructed of 4 rectangular strips; each strip will have a length and a width (that will vary per square but be uniform for each individual square).

The 4" x 4" square in the center is the highest value product. The second hollow square that envelops that square is the second highest value product. And so on until you reach the fourth square that is the lowest value product.

Therefore I want the second square to have dimensions such that it is as "thick" as possible given the remaining 20 square inches, and the last square to be the "thinnest" square with dimensions that make it such. And the third in-between square can depend on the other two.

I am wondering how I could possibly approach this problem in Python. It is definitely above my current skill set, though I tend to learn and understand quickly! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A drawing would really help here, I think. However, this also really just sounds like a minimization/maximization problem, so if you can formulate this in terms of an equation whose result to minimize or maximize, `scipy` has functions for that.

Comment: This question is too close to the 'real world' problem for SO.  For SO you need to convert it into a task involving python objects, and for `scipy` use `numpy arrays`.  SO is best  for coding problems and errors.  Someone may help you conceptualize the task, but don't count on it, and expect a lot questions and/or assumptions.

Comment: @NickODell Yes I realized I left out some key information (that I actually realized I don't even have myself yet) which is that these are theoretically real cuts that are going to be made by a sawmill blade, so there's only so small you can go before the blade can't cut that thin and/or the board has no retail value at that thickness (these will really be 3D boards but the surface area is the part that really needs to be optimized). I will have to ask our consultant what the minimum dimensions allowed per square are. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with the writing of the question itself that make it hard to answer.
First of all, you use box and square interchangeably, is this a 2 dimensional object?
Second, are you intending on assigning specific values for the areas of the different tiers? If not, you could simply make the first one 5.99 units to a side, assuming you cannot make it reach the edge for some reason. What exactly are you wanting to optimize for?

Even assuming the first cut needs to be exactly 4 units to a side, if you want to second 'box' to be as thick as possible it should be the rest of the surface area, and you should not have a 3rd or 4th box (or the 3rd and 4th boxes should be as small as allowed).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response; I'll try and edit my post and use a different word for "box, as the objects in question right now are 2D. Eventually they'll be 2D, but that won't be part of the problem. In terms of assigning specific values for area, my problem lies in that I want to make the first hollow square the hollow square with the largest area and the outermost hollow square with the smallest area, but am not sure how to determine the dimensions that would achieve that.

Comment: And I do see what you're saying in the last paragraph; maybe the issue with this problem is that it doesn't correlate well to the real-life scenario, which is sawing the rectangular cant of a log. The default is to have the four squares, but maybe I actually need to clarify the minimum dimensions of each square based on what the saw can feasibly cut.

Comment: @RMoazed Please do edit in the actual real-life scenario into the original question - it will help understanding your problem.

Comment: @AKX thank you I will once I find out! Stack Overflow closed the question because there was too much going on lol so I'll probably have to post a more streamlined question once I have that info